# What effects will a 220 to 110 transformer have on an electric oven?

Tags: converter

I'm a Jewish person looking to bake matzah, which in English is called unleavened bread. There are particular ways to do this, and particular ovens to get, but most of these things are made in Israel. Here is an example of one of these ovens.

[image]

The question is, since this product is designed to work in Israel, which is 220, would this product work here in the US with a transformer? And if it does work, will there be any change in functionality? For example, would there be any issues of the oven not getting to its intended peak temperature, or possibly taking too long to get to it.

Comment: See also [a related question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/66308/details-of-matzah-oven) on Judaism Stack Exchange.  It was asked by the same asker.

Comment: Dear OP:  Electronics _usage_ questions are off-topic here.  Next time, please ask such questions elsewhere.  DIY Stack Exchange, or the electricians' sub-Reddit, might accept such questions; check with them.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using a transformer, run the oven from a 220 V outlet, like you find for a clothes dryer or cooking range.  That should be close enough to the right voltage.  The heater is just a resistor, so should have some leaway, especially since it's probably controlled by a thermostat.

The biggest difference will be the 60 Hz here versus the 50 Hz the oven was designed for.  A transformer won't fix that either.  It's probably not a problem though.  Again, the heating elements won't care, but there is a off chance that the power supply for the control electronics will have some issues.  Again, I think there's only a slim chance of that.

Answer (score 2):

It should work fine if the transformer is rated for the power level of the oven.  You should allow an bit extra for safety.  For example, if the oven is rated at 100 watts, then a 220 volt to 120 volt transformer rated for at least 125 watts should be used.